# A grid of buttons using UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to create a grid with buttons. Most of the sample applications I saw explain how to create grid of images but neither one explains for buttons.

How to set a button in `UICollectionView`'s cell?

Here is my code,

**FirstViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *myCollectView;
@end
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()
{
    NSArray *arrayOfBtns;
}
@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self myCollectView]setDelegate:self];
    [[self myCollectView]setDataSource:self];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    arrayOfBtns=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Save",@"Goto", nil];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayOfBtns count];
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //[[cell btn]setText:[arrayOfBtns objectAtIndex:indexPath.item  ]];
    return cell;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

**CustomCell.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;

@end
```

**CustomCell.m**

```
 #import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The cell you're dequeuing is not a `CustomCell` because you've not told the `UICollectionView` to use `CustomCell` as the reusable cell.

In `viewDidLoad:`, add this line:

> [[self myCollectionView] registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //[cell.btn setText:[arrayOfBtns objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    return cell;
}
```

the cell is nil.  you should regist the custom cell for the CellIdentifier.

Answer (score -1):

You can find how to create custom cells here: http://www.goapps.pl/blog/perfecting-uitableview-step-one-custom-cells/

Comment: This is for `UITableView cells`, not `UICollectionView` cells.